# Visual Studio workspace tasks Unexpected error

Tags: visual-studio-code

The way I run the code in Visual Studio code is Shift+Ctrl+B. But suddenly the code doesn't work. It prints the following message.

`Unexpected: Tasks can only be run in a workspace folder`

I would appreciate it if you can tell me how to fix it.

- I use Python

Answer (score 1):

I just updated and this started happening to me also.

Solution seems to be to do a "File/Open Folder" on the folder where your build scripts are that need to run.

In my case I have a build task that just runs a batch file, so if I do a file open folder on the folder where the batch file is,  my  CTRL_SHIFT_B works again and it runs the batch file.

This is not a great answer because I don't understand why this limitation has been introduced, but might help you till someone can explain whats going on better.